# How can I get capslock recognized as a keybind for wow, or remap it in macos?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gaming, key-binding

Long time wow player here.  I've recently made the transition from a windows machine to my first mac.

All my keybinds came along with me when i transferred the data.  The in-game GUI does show that my keybind is set correctly as capslock which was the case on my windows machine.

All other binds work fine barring the aforementioned which the game does not register as a key press.  the key is functioning in its intended behavior via capitalizing all my text in chat, but outside of that.. I cannot bind it whatsoever.

i assume this has something to do with the way mac views it as a "modifier" so i'd like to circumvent that behavior so I can use it as a keystroke/keybind like any other key in world of warcraft, or remap it to another key as the less desirable but better than nothing option.  My muscle memory over almost 20 years necessitates it.